# Express.js: file not found (even though it is there)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building a web whiteboard for my college project, using node.js,express.js, validator js, raphael.js,jquery and uglify.js and socket.io
I just made a server script and added node_modules using npm install in the command prompt. All the required libraries were installed.here is the server code

```
    var
    port = +process.argv[2] || 8080,

    sanitizer = require('validator').sanitize,
    express = require('express'),

    server = express.createServer(),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    chat = io.of('/chat'),
    canvas = io.of('/canvas')
;

function sanitize(string) {
    return sanitizer(string).entityDecode()
}

server.listen(port);

server.get(/(^\/.*$)/, function(request, response) {
    var fileName = request.params[0];
    if (fileName == '/')
        fileName = '/index.html';
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client' + fileName);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('setName', function (name) {
        name = sanitize(name);
        socket.set('name', name);
        socket.broadcast.emit('receive', {
            sender:'Server',
            message:name + ' has joined.'
        })
    });

    socket.on('send', function (message) {
        socket.get('name', function(error, name) {
            if (name)
                socket.broadcast.emit('receive', {
                    sender:name,
                    message:sanitize(message)
                })
        })
    });

    socket.on('draw', function (command) {
        io.sockets.emit('draw', command)
    });

    socket.on('updateCursor', function(position) {
        socket.get('name', function(error, name) {
            if (name)
                socket.broadcast.emit('updateCursor', {
                    name:name,
                    position:position
                });
        });
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        socket.get('name', function(error, name) {
            if (name) {
                socket.broadcast.emit('receive', {
                    sender:'Server',
                    message:name + ' has left.'
                });
                socket.broadcast.emit('removeCursor', name);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

However, when i run this server code in command prompt, i get this error

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Akshay\Desktop\whiteboard-master\whiteboard-master\server.js:5:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

Now, i installed the express.js in the node_modules folder, where the code was supposed to look. i still got the same error. I also tried removing it from there, and installing express.js globally.I recently updated to express.js vs 3.4. I am still getting the same error.
Can someone help me?? I have to submit the project in a week's time.

Comment: You should install `express`, not `express.js`.

Comment: thanks, but now i am getting another error, it says express.createServer() is is not a function. what do i do?

Comment: `express.createServer()` has been deprecated in Express 4 (the latest version). How to create server with that version [is documented here](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html).

Comment: I tried that too, but now i am getting an error with socket.io
Error: You are trying to attach socket.io to an express request handler function. Please pass a http.Server instance.
I made the following changes
server=express(),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server),

Comment: The server is returned by `app.listen()`.

Comment: Thank you again!, it works now!